# WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop while running a test

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I got a test which fails with stacktrace below. I am unsure why this happens. The test runs for 30 seconds, and looks a bit like this:

```
@Test
fun test() = runBlocking {
    // Test code...
    delay(1000)
    // Test code...
    delay(1000)
    // Repeat...
}
```

When using print statements (because I can not use the debugger) I can see that the error is triggered while calling the delay function. The problem is: I **need** those calls since I wait in a non-coroutine scope for network responses (it's a bit pseudo code as well but mimics a bit how it works).

How can I resolve this problem?

```
04-24 16:45:15.324 19754 19754 W GCM     : broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.myappapp.myapp (has extras) }
04-24 16:45:15.331   588 25843 I system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 25662
04-24 16:45:15.332   268   268 I tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 25662 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
04-24 16:45:15.332 25662 25667 I eezleapp.myapp: Thread[6,tid=25667,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb400007d034d82c0,peer=0x13dc0000,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
04-24 16:45:15.332 25662 25667 I eezleapp.myapp:
04-24 16:45:15.355   268   268 I tombstoned: received crash request for pid 25662
04-24 16:45:15.355   268   268 I tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 25662 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
04-24 16:45:15.355 25662 25667 I eezleapp.myapp: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
04-24 16:45:15.355   268   268 W tombstoned: skipping tombstone file creation due to intercept
04-24 16:45:15.355   588 25843 I system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 25662
04-24 16:45:15.365   588   620 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10164 pid 25662 in 5ms
04-24 16:45:15.382 19853 19853 D BoundBrokerSvc: onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.measurement.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
04-24 16:45:15.384   368   368 I Zygote  : Process 25662 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
04-24 16:45:15.386   905  1172 D BtGatt.ScanManager: uid 10106 isForeground true scanMode -1
04-24 16:45:15.386   905  1172 D BtGatt.ScanManager: uid 10106 isForeground true scanMode -1
04-24 16:45:15.397 25648 25648 I app_process: System.exit called, status: 0
04-24 16:45:15.397 25648 25648 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
04-24 16:45:15.404 19754 19754 W GCM     : broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.myappapp.myapp (has extras) }
```